# How to validate Excel data to protect against XSS?

Tags: webserver, xss, java

My application is dynamically constructing a source URL and then writing the resource file (Excel) directly to the response. The URL is read from a properties file, based on the application environment. (Not related to user input!)

Our scanning tool is reporting a XSS vulnerability on `BufferedOutputStream.write()`: "Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page".

- Is this a valid error?
- If so, how can I protect the user from this?

I believe the Excel data will be XML, so it would not be possible to strip out tags.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException


    {

    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    OutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
    BufferedOutputStream ros = null;
    InputStream iStr = null;
    BufferedInputStream bistr = null;

    res.setContentType(mimeType);
try
    {
        ros = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        URL location = new URL(resourceName);
        URLConnection input = location.openConnection();//remote excel file

        int len = input.getContentLength();
        res.setContentLength(len);

        iStr = input.getInputStream();
        bistr = new BufferedInputStream(iStr);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while(-1 != (bytesRead = bistr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)))
        {
            ros.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274590/outputstream-writing-a-bytearray-xss-prevention